# What does "while (1<<n) < self.top:" mean?

Tags: python, while-loop

I saw this statement in the source code of Scapy in volatile.py.
What is the meaning of `(1 << n)` in the `while` condition?

```
def __init__(self, inf, sup, seed=None, forever=1, renewkeys=0):
    self.forever = forever
    self.renewkeys = renewkeys
    self.inf = inf
    self.rnd = random.Random(seed)
    self.sbox_size = 256

    self.top = sup-inf+1

    n=0
    while (1<<n) < self.top:
        n += 1
    self.n =n

    self.fs = min(3,(n+1)/2)
    self.fsmask = 2**self.fs-1
    self.rounds = max(self.n,3)
    self.turns = 0
    self.i = 0
```

Comment: `<<` is the [shift left operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators). `1 << n` is the same as `2` to the power of `n`.

Comment: for curiosity sake, does python automatically not automatically try to optimize this? This code is amusing in that it uses 2**self.fs notation later on

Comment: @Untitled123 no, it's not possible; one of the disadvantages of a dynamic language is there's no way of telling that (for example) accessing `self.top` doesn't have a side-effect that modifies the value.

Comment: how would self.top have a side effect? Also, I was referring to optimizing 2**n to 1<<n

Comment: @Untitled123: `self.top` could be a property; the class could have its getattr behaviour tweaked; etc.  Simply accessing `self.top` could execute arbitrary code.

Comment: @Untitled123 `self.top` may be a derived value such as an `@property` or something managed by the object's `__get_attribute__` method. The object top references may override its magic operators to implement comparisons differently. So, python has to go through all the steps each time it accesses the object.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PAyLbdAv  this is the ful text of the volitile.py in case you are curious and don't want to guess. https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/src - here is the full source of Scapy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<< is a bitwise operator, as explained [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators):

> x << y Returns x with the bits shifted to the left by y places (and
>   new bits on the right-hand-side are zeros). This is the same as
>   multiplying x by 2**y.

---

so here in the code you provided, the while loop goes until the biggest power of 2 number which is less than `self.top` , if we assume self.top is 100 , the biggest power of two which is less than 100 is 64, if it were 200, it would go until 128

```
In [17]: n = 0
In [18]: top = 100
In [19]: while ( 1 << n ) < top:
    ...:     print ( 1<<n)
    ...:     n+=1
    ...:     
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
```

Comment: Thats fancy.Thank you.